# When we use Azure data lake store as data source for Azure Analysis services, is Parquet file formats are supported?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

Could you please help with sample tutorial if 'Parquet" file formats are supported when we use data lake as data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great question!  Parquet is unfortunately not supported as a source directly for Azure Analysis Services.  What you could do is store the parquet files either in Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake, and then use one of the services such as [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#parquet-format) or [Azure Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-parquet.html) which do support Parquet natively to convert it.  You could even use Polybase from Azure SQL Data Warehouse to point directly at the Parquet files.  A conversion / transform might be required if encryption is used for example.

Here are a few example patterns but you should think about what is best for your business:

[image: sample HLDs for Parquet and AAS]

Good luck!